# Can I view Npgsql performance counters by connection string?

Tags: postgresql, npgsql

I just upgraded to Npgsql 3.2.5 and I'm using [performance counters](http://www.npgsql.org/doc/performance.html#performance-counters) (`Use Perf Counters=True;`). My application connects to four different database servers. I assume there is a separate pool for each connection string / server.

**Can I view the counters by connection string / server?**

Answer (score 0):

You're right that the connections are pooled by "server" (by matching connection strings). I don't see anything in the [performance counter code](https://github.com/npgsql/npgsql/blob/dev/src/Npgsql/Counters.cs), though, that makes a similar differentiation.

This might make for a good feature request!